# Use multiple dictionaries for cmu sphinx

Tags: dictionary, cmusphinx, sphinx4, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

For my project the default dictionary provided by the Sphinx is not sufficient.
I need to use another custom dictionary along with the provided dictionary.

Now my question is that is there any way of specifying multiple dictionary files to Sphinx or do I need to combine both the dictionaries into a single big dictionary file? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine dictionaries into single one.

Comment: and I suppose it should be sorted alphabetically? or I can simply append the second dictionary below first one?

Comment: It is better to sort properly.

Comment: @ASHUTOSH: can you guide me how to combine dictionaries into single one ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple dictionaries with Sphinx, what I did was to make my program delete the previous dictionary and write another one to the same file path with the different words you want to use. This can be done back and forth as many times as you like to give the impression of multiple dictionaries.