# CMUSphinx merge multiple dictionary into single one?

Tags: java, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

Im working on cmusphinx speech to text, I need to train/add words to my dictionary, so i used [lmtool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html) and uploaded a corpus file and used the .dict and .lm file and used these as parameters for pocketsphinx and it worked. Im wondering how to add these files to default files. i.e i want to add the new words .dict and .lm files to `/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict` and `/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin`

Im not sure, if this is feasible and im wondering how to combine dictionaries into single one. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142833/use-multiple-dictionaries-for-cmu-sphinx) but not sure how to achieve the same.

When i use the [TranscriberDemo.java](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java) my wav file has different words and the output prints different. how to improve the accuracy ?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary and language model extension is covered in the following part of tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallmadvanced

Comment: thanks for the response, I went through the link, as a starter, im not able to understand things like mix, pruning, is there is any guidance/steps provided in documentation combine multiple dictionary files to Sphinx, sry for my ignorance.